# How can we prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|\cos(1^2)|+|\cos (2^2)|+\cdots+|\cos (n^2)|}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can we prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{|\cos(1^2)|+|\cos (2^2)|+\cdots+|\cos (n^2)|}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}$?

I have tried to use Stolz's formula,but unfortunately, it failed,since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|\cos ((n+1)^2)|}{(n+1)-n}$$
is not exists.
The problem is too difficult for me to work it out.

Comment: Maybe the power series of $cos$ can help?

Comment: Stolz's formula states:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\mathcal{l}$$
This would state:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\cos(n^2)|}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\cos((n+1)^2)|-|\cos(n^2)|$$. This does not really help with your problem

Comment: The values of the sequence $n^2$ are equidistributed modulo $\pi$, so terms in your limit approximate the average value of $|\cos(x)|$ (which is $\pi$-periodic) on the interval $[0,\pi]$, which is precisely $2/\pi$. I don't know if this is the simplest possible argument.

Comment: Your ideas are very enlightening，I will have a try!

Answer (score 10):

Rewrite the generic term to average as
$$|\cos(n^2)| = \left|\cos\left(\pi \frac{n^2}{\pi}\right)\right| =
\left|\cos\left(\pi \left\{\frac{n^2}{\pi}\right\}\right)\right|$$
where $u_n = \frac{n^2}{\pi}$ and $\{\cdot\}$ stands for the fractional part.

We know $\pi$ is irrational. So for any positive integer $h$,
$\frac{2h}{\pi}$ is irrational.
By [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem), the sequence

$$\{ u_{n+h} - u_n \} = \left\{\frac{2h}{\pi} n + \frac{h^2}{\pi}\right\}$$

is equidistributed modulo $1$.

Since this is true for all positive integer $h$, [van der Corput's difference theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanderCorputsTheorem.html) tells us $u_n$ is also equidistributed modulo $1$.

Recall for any Riemann integrable function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and any sequence $(s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ equidistributed on $[a,b]$, we have

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f(s_n) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

Apply this to $f(x) = |\cos(\pi x)|$ and $s_n = u_n$, we obtain

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N|\cos(n^2)| = \int_0^1 |\cos(\pi x)| dx = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the fact that:
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$$
But for the whole summation if this is possible?