# How to evaluate $\lim_{{n}\to\infty}{\sum_{{k}\leq{n}}{\left\lvert\frac{\sin{k}}{\ln{n^k}}\right\rvert}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

> Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n{\mspace{-2mu}\frac{\left\lvert\sin{k}\right\rvert}{k}}\sim\frac{2}{\pi}\mspace{-1.5mu}\sum_{k=1}^n{\mspace{-2mu}\frac{1}{\mspace{-1mu}k}}$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Alternatively, since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\ln{x}}\mspace{-1.5mu}\int_0^x{\mspace{-2mu}\frac{\left\lvert\sin{t}\right\rvert}{t}\operatorname{d}\!t}$ converges to $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ as $x\to{+\infty}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{{\it{H}}_n}{\ln{n}}}=1$, how can we prove that $$\sum_{{1}\leq{n}\leq{\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor}}{\mspace{-2mu}\frac{\left\lvert\sin{n}\right\rvert}{n}}\sim\int_0^x{\mspace{-2mu}\frac{\left\lvert\sin{t}\right\rvert}{t}\operatorname*{d}\!t}$$ as $x\to{+\infty}$?

- It may seem like just one simple application of the so-called [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251285299_The_Summation_Formulae_of_Euler-Maclaurin_Abel-Plana_Poisson_and_their_Interconnections_with_the_Approximate_Sampling_Formula_of_Signal_Analysis). Nonetheless, $\dfrac{\left\lvert\sin{u}\right\rvert}{u}$ is not always continuously differentiable on $\left[0, x\right]$, hence the use of the [Euler–Maclaurin summation formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E1) shall be inadmissible in fact.
- So does the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stolzcesaro-theorem/).

Some "similar" problems can be seen in many posts such as [How can we prove that …](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3208347), [How to prove the convergence of the series?](https://www.zhihu.com/question/413589992) and [How to find the limit…](https://www.zhihu.com/question/403779256).

Comment: I would suggesting finding an asymptotic formula, with error term, for $\sum_{k\le x} |\sin k|$ (using equidistribution of the integers modulo $\pi$, similar in spirit to the links you provided), and then using partial summation to incorporate the factor $\frac1k$.

Comment: The sequence $\{ k/\pi\}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1]$. Therefore $\sum_{k \leqslant n} \lvert \sin k\rvert \sim \frac{2}{\pi}n$. Sum by parts.